# pixel.quant.server forever

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I wanted to comment this post
[Sample code for Own OpenId Server in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585204/sample-code-for-own-openid-server-in-asp-net)

After I validate, the 2 antispam guy shows up briefly and then disappear as the browser is redirected to pixel.quant.server forever.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by validate? Who are these antispam guys?

Comment: What is even more impressive is his name as commenter on this question, surprisingly shortened as "asksuperu"

Comment: @Gnoupi - that's weird - maybe his username changed between asking the question and commenting, and only one of the relevant places got updated. Really weird.

Comment: Do you mean the "funny" human verification form: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/are-you-a-human-being/?

Comment: Very weird: There's also no name on his SO user profile.

Answer (score 1):

we can't reproduce this.